# Add an automated message to posts that have at least 1 "Close as [Low Quality]" vote

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, off-topic, low-quality-posts, not-a-real-question

As a >3k rep user on SO, I try to do my part and cast close votes on low quality questions. For new users, I've tried to be a good citizen in the past and leave a comment with  suggestions to improve their answers.

I've stopped doing this though because I've noticed that it's pretty common in the 24 hours after I've left one of these comments to see a dramatic increase in suspicious activity in my server logs.

In the vein of the "Kinder Gentler Close" procedure that's being discussed in meta right now, I'd like to propose that an automated comment be added as soon as a question receives one or more votes to close it as low quality: e.g. Off Topic or NaRQ (or whatever the new categories will be).

Maybe something like this:

> ### Your question is in danger of being closed
>
> The SO community is voting that this question is [Low Quality Reason(s)]. It isn't close yet, but it is likely to be closed soon. [More detailed reason specific explanation here].

Comment: I'm going to link to this post in future when someone suggest that downvoters should be forced to leave a comment. *"see a dramatic increase in suspicious activity in my server logs"* sums up exactly why that's not a good idea.

Comment: A similar proposal here ["This question will be closed soon if not edited!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105832/provide-a-this-question-will-be-closed-soon-if-not-edited-close-reason-for-lo?rq=1)